# Can't install Mono on OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, mono, osx-lion

I'm trying to install the Mono Framework, MRE 2.11.4, on Mac OS X 10.8.2 Mountain Lion. When I double click on the downloaded package file, I get the maddening message '"MonoFramework - MRE-22.11.4.macos10.xamarin.x86.pkg" can't be opened because it is from an unidentified developer.' Okay, now what? How do I install this on my Mac? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Command click it to open the context menu and select "Open". The next dialog will give you a chance to run it. This is the [official way](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5290) of bypassing the "Gatekeeper" protection.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. This answer seemed so close to the surface that I guessed it's in the Mac help. I clicked the question mark button and sure enough the answer is there. Dah!